# delete punctuation in special cases

Tags: python

this is an example of how I am tokenizing a phrase for my language that is Spanish.

```
texto= "esto es un texto, para el sr. gómez. Esto; es una prueba que puedes encontrar en www.google.com quisiera encontrarla.. claro esta,.Quisiera mejorarlo"
```

when I use nltk that tokenizes my phrase, this is the output:

```
['esto', 'es', 'un', 'texto', ',', 'para', 'el', 'sr.', 'gómez', '.', 'Esto', ';', 'es', 'una', 'prueba', 'que', 'puedes', 'encontrar', 'en', 'www.google.com','quiero','encontarla..','esta,.', 'quisiera','mejoralo']
```

how can I eliminate the punctuation except for valid scores like `sr.` or `www.google.com`

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
texto= "esto es un texto, para el sr. gómez. Esto; es una prueba que puedes encontrar en www.google.com quisiera encontrarla.."
palabras_tokenizadas=(word_tokenize(texto,"spanish"))
print(palabras_tokenizadas)
```

this should be the result:

```
['esto', 'es', 'un', 'texto',  'para', 'el', 'sr.', 'gómez',  'Esto',  'es', 'una', 'prueba', 'que', 'puedes', 'encontrar', 'en', 'www.google.com', 'quisiera', 'encontrarla', 'claro', 'esta', 'quisiera', 'mejorarlo']
```

I tried something like this, but it does not solve my problem (problem with words like`"encontarla.."`, `"esta,."`

```
punctuation = [",", ";", ".",...............] # The tokens that I want to skip
palabras_tokenizadas_1 = [ palabra for palabra in palabras_tokenizadas if palabra not in punctuation ]
```

I would like to make the best way to solve my problem globally in any sentence that has a score, not just fix the problem to this sentence. How can do it?

Comment: It's not clear to me why `"encontarla.."`, `"esta,."` are special cases. Is it because they end in *two* punctuation marks? (Unlike `"sr."`)

Comment: @BoarGules Exactly .. Nltk intelligently separates "sr." that in my language is the same as "mr.", that's because those 2 are special cases. if I do something to replace all the "." in my sentence, the result would also be affected for words like "sr." and "www.google.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> rxx = re.compile(r'([^.,]*)([.,]{2,})')     # Extend [.,] as needed (twice);  {2,} means >= 2
>>> a=["encontarla..", "esta,.", "sr.", "texto", "ellipsis...", "infinitecommas" + 32767 * ","]
>>> [rxx.sub(lambda m: m.group(1), word) for word in a]
['encontarla', 'esta', 'sr.', 'texto', 'ellipsis', 'infinitecommas']
```

`nltk` knows quite a lot about regular expressions so you might be able to get the tokenizer to apply this mod itself.

Comment: I am amazed by your intelligence, but if a word has "n" ellipsis, it eliminates only the first 2. This should delete all ellipsis

Comment: @unusuario You are quite correct. I did test it, but obviously not thoroughly enough. Fixed in an edit.